# ¿Cómo añadir más colores a las barras de progreso?

Tags: css, bootstrap, progressbar

Querría poner màs colores a las barras de progreso. He buscado por el código y la documentación de bootstrap, pero  no logro enterarme de como puedo poner mas colores que los que se ven. Quizá no se pueda, pues todos los ejemplos vienen con los mismos. Me queda duda pues no todos tiene el mismo tono o intensidad de color. 
Gracias

```css
/*creado con la ayuda de Edgar Gutiérrez*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic');
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #666;
  background-color: #fff;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

p.lead {
  font-weight: 600;
}

a {
  color: #28c3ab;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #176e61;
}

.light {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.navbar-brand h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-brand:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
  outline: 0;
}

#preloader {
  background: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#loaderInner {
  background: #ffffff url(../img/spinner.gif) center center no-repeat;
  height: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 60px;
}

@keyframes boxSpin {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-10px, 0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
}

@keyframes shadowSpin {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 10px -10px #39CCCC, -10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px #39CCCC, -10px -10px #FFDC00;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: -10px 10px #39CCCC, 10px -10px #FFDC00;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: -10px -10px #39CCCC, 10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 10px -10px #39CCCC, -10px 10px #FFDC00;
  }
}

#load {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #FF4136;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -5px auto 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 5px solid #FF4136;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px #39CCCC, 10px 0px #01FF70;
  animation: shadowSpin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.marginbot-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.marginbot-10 {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.marginbot-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.marginbot-30 {
  margin-bottom: 30px !important;
}

.marginbot-40 {
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
}

.marginbot-50 {
  margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.home-section {
  padding-top: 110px;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 120;
}

.section-heading h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.section-heading i {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bg-white {
  background: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.bg-dark {
  background: #575757;
}

.text-light {
  color: #fff;
}

.intro {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://i64.tinypic.com/2q21qq1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: auto;
}

#intro.intro {
  padding: 20% 0 0 0;
}

.intro .slogan {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro .page-scroll {
  text-align: center;
}

.brand-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.intro-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.intro .slogan h2 {
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: none;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 1px #000;
}

.intro .slogan h4 {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #000;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .intro .slogan h2 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .intro .slogan h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}

.boxed-grey {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 20px;
}

.team h5 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.team p.subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.avatar {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.team-social {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.team-social {
  text-align: center;
}

.team-social li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

.team-social a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3bbec0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.team-social a i {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.team-social .social-facebook a {
  background: #3873ae;
}

.team-social .social-twitter a {
  background: #62c6f8;
}

.team-social .social-dribble a {
  background: #d74980;
}

.team-social .social-deviantart a {
  background: #8da356;
}

.team-social .social-google a {
  background: #000;
}

.team-social .social-vimeo a {
  background: #51a6d3;
}

.team-social .social-facebook a:hover {
  background: #4893ce;
}

.team-social .social-twitter a:hover {
  background: #82e6ff;
}

.team-social .social-dribble a:hover {
  background: #f769a0;
}

.team-social .social-deviantart a:hover {
  background: #adc376;
}

.team-social .social-google a:hover {
  background: #333;
}

.team-social .social-vimeo a:hover {
  background: #71c6f3;
}

.service-icon {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form#contact-form .form-group label {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

form#contact-form input,
form#contact-form select,
form#contact-form textarea {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

form#contact-form input:focus,
form#contact-form select:focus,
form#contact-form textarea:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.input-group-addon {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.widget-contact {
  text-align: left;
}

.validation {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#sendmessage {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#errormessage {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#sendmessage.show,
#errormessage.show,
.show {
  display: block;
}

.company-social {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.company-social {
  text-align: left;
}

.company-social li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

.company-social a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3bbec0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.company-social a i {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.company-social .social-facebook a {
  background: #3873ae;
}

.company-social .social-twitter a {
  background: #62c6f8;
}

.company-social .social-dribble a {
  background: #d74980;
}

.company-social .social-deviantart a {
  background: #8da356;
}

.company-social .social-google a {
  background: #000;
}

.company-social .social-vimeo a {
  background: #51a6d3;
}

.company-social .social-facebook a:hover {
  background: #4893ce;
}

.company-social .social-twitter a:hover {
  background: #82e6ff;
}

.company-social .social-dribble a:hover {
  background: #f769a0;
}

.company-social .social-deviantart a:hover {
  background: #adc376;
}

.company-social .social-google a:hover {
  background: #333;
}

.company-social .social-vimeo a:hover {
  background: #71c6f3;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

footer p {
  color: #f8f8f8;
}

.credits,
.credits a {
  color: #fff;
}


/* ==========================
Parallax
============================= */

#parallax1 {
  background-image: url(../img/parallax/1.jpg);
}

#parallax1:after {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: -1;
}

#parallax2 {
  background-image: url(../img/parallax/2.jpg);
}

#parallax2:after {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark {
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
}

.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #999;
  background: #fff;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover i,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus i {
  color: #999;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle i.animated {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle:hover i.animated {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -moz-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0 {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

#text {
  color: #fff;
  background: #ffcc00;
}

#map {
  height: 500px;
}

.btn-skin:hover,
.btn-skin:focus,
.btn-skin:active,
.btn-skin.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  border: 1px solid #28c3ab;
  outline: 0;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #28c3ab;
}

.btn-huge {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.banner-social-buttons {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .top-nav-collapse {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  }
  .intro {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .brand-heading {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .intro-text {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .team.boxed-grey {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .boxed-grey {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .tp-banner-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .page-scroll a.btn-circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 7px 0;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

html .nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

html .nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Algunas de mis habilidades en el desarrollo web...</p>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%">
          90% - html
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
          40% - CSS
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%">
          50% - Javascript.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
          80% - Uso de interfaz.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
          80% - Uso de interfaz.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
          80% - Uso de interfaz.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo creando tus propias clases y añadiendolas en lugar de las de Bootstrap, por ejemplo podrías reemplazar `progress-bar-danger` por `progress-bar-purple`, y utilizar los colores que tu quieras.

Se debe agregar el `!important`, ya que si no se define un color se tomará el color por defecto que define Bootstrap en `progress-bar`

```css
.progress-bar-green {
  background-color: rgb(8, 221, 17) !important;
}

.progress-bar-yellow {
  background-color: rgb(219, 217, 7) !important;
}

.progress-bar-purple {
  background-color: rgb(134, 3, 205) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
    <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-yellow progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
    <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-purple progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
    <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias compañero @kacospro, no quería utilizar mucho el `!important;` , ley que no conviene abusar. Pero he visto que Bootstrap de por si ya los trae. Gracias.

Comment: Si @MiguelEspeso en efecto no hay que abusar del `!important`, intenté no integrarlo pero no agarraba los colores en el snippet, pero en mi navegador sí, pruebalo y me cuentas como te fue ;)

Comment: Perfecto compi, funciona sin el `!important; ` y en el body  lo siguiente `          <div class="progress progress-striped active">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-yellow " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                80% Complete
              </div>
            </div>`    Gracias por tu apoyo.